# how to add a new column to a pandas dataframe using apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add 2 new column to a pandas dataframe.

```
items = df["item_name"]


groupedWeights = [re.findall('(\d+(?:ml| ml|g| g|gm| gm))', i) for i in items]
flattenedWeights = [y for x in groupedWeights for y in x]



groupedCounts = [re.findall('(\d+(?:x| x|pk| pk|pack| pack|packs| packs))', i) for i in items]
groupedCounts.append([re.findall('((?:pack of |pack of | packs of)+\d+)', i) for i in items])
flattenedCounts = [y for x in groupedCounts for y in x]



df.to_csv('newColumns.csv', index = False)
```

Tried

```
#df['flattenedWeights'] = pd.Series(flattenedWeights)
#df['flattenedCounts'] = pd.Series(flattenedCounts)
```

and it works but it gets all the values that are not empty to the top of the column and all the empty ones are at the bottom. I need them to be in the same order as the df's index, but since the  df index is 8k and the new ones have around 6k because some of them are empty...

Also tried

```
def fab():
    groupedWeights = [re.findall('(\d+(?:ml| ml|g| g|gm| gm))', i) for i in items]
    flattenedWeights = [y for x in groupedWeights for y in x]
df['newcolumn'] = df.apply(fab, axis=1)
```

and

```
df["flattenedWeights"] = df.apply(flattenedWeights, axis=1)
```

but without any luck.

Comment: Can you add some data sample to question and expected ouput?

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
df['some_name'] = df['name'].apply(col_data)
```

if your function requires multiple cols u can use:

```
df['new_column_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_function(x['value_1'], x['value_2']), axis=1)
```

Comment: Did you read that I have tried this already and it doesn't work?:)

Comment: @Osiris did you try adding a return statement at the end of your fab function bcz it is not return anything, or else try to make it like a lambda function implementation

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
df['item_size'] = df['item_name'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('(\d+(?:ml| ml|g| g|l| l|gm| gm|kg|cl| kg|kg | cl|cl ))', x))

df['item_count'] = df['item_name'].apply(lambda y: re.findall('(\d+(?:x| x|pk| pk|pack| pack| pack of |packs| packs| pack of|pack of | packs of))', y))
```